# ion-select doesn't show full text

Tags: ionic3, ion-select

ion-selects in my form don't show full text of its ion-option

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post full HTML or div where actually ion-select added ?

Comment: <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-9>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-select formControlName="articulo1">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let producto of productos" [value]="producto.prod">{{producto.prod}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input formControlName="palets1" type="number" [value]=palets1></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

Comment: @Fomare It would be best if you added your code to the question and not as a comment so it is formatted properly.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

CSS

```
.myCustomSelect{
    max-width: 100% !important;
   }
```

HTML

```
<ion-select class= "myCustomSelect" [(ngModel)]="pedido">
      ....
 </ion-select>
```

Source: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5427

Comment: You are my hero, Thank You :)

Comment: could you please suggest me how can i develop my custom theme in ionic 4? I have more than 10 years experience in IT field but newer to ionic. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same issue , I solved it by putting this in  `app.scss` file:

```
ion-label{

white-space:normal !important;

}
```

Comment: for ios platform i put this and resolved my problem
.alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-ios {
  white-space:normal !important;
}